# Does limiting plant size decrease life-span?

Tags: container-gardening

So, I'm looking into growing plants indoors(specifically, trees such as Meyer Lemons and possibly apples). It's my understanding that a plant's size can be limited by keeping it in a small pot, and trimming it's roots if it becomes root-locked. Assuming this is all correct, would this decrease the plant's life-span? If so, would it mature faster as well?

Comment: Apples are unlikely to be successful indoors. Light levels will be inadequate, and they need a few weeks of cold temperatures in winter (colder than you would want to live in - below 50F or 10C, 24 hours a day) to induce flowering in spring.

Comment: For fruit plants, you limit size by choosing a suitable variety of root plant. (Near all fruit plants are grafted, so you just choose the right "bottom"). All grafting reduce lifetime, OTOH old plant may not produce so much, so it is convenient to replace them

Comment: You will get root bind which will kill your own trees as the roots grow essentially suffocating themselves.

Comment: I plan on pruning the roots if a plant get root bind, and hopefully I'll prevent it from happening by pruning the top. At least, that's my plan